Struggling with recursive stepping algorithm
I have a table of data where I need to find a looping path based on a comparison of two columns. I generated a very simplied sample table below.
$max = 10
$testdata = for($i=1; $i -le $max; $i++) {
    $item1 = "item{0:D2}" -f (Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum $max)
    $item2 = do { "item{0:D2}" -f (Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum $max) } until ($_ -ne $item1)
    $item3 = do { "item{0:D2}" -f (Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum $max) } until ($_ -ne $item1 -or $_ -ne $item2)

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Row   = "Row{0:D2}" -f $i
        Item1 = $item1
        Cost1 = Get-Random -Minimum 20 -Maximum 800
        Item2 = $item2
        Cost2 = Get-Random -Minimum 80 -Maximum 400
        Item3 = $item3
        Cost3 = Get-Random -Minimum 60 -Maximum 600
    }
}

For each row, I need to compare it's Item1 value to Item2 for the entire table. For each match, I need to then search it's Item1 for a match in the table's Item2. Repeat until all possible matches are done. The end goal is to find a path that loops back on itself. For example:  Row1 > Row5 > Row3 > Row1. Each match has an associated cost which is represented as a simplified value above. Its much more complicated but I can deal with that calulation later, which is a total sum associated with each looping result.
I have a somewhat working function that does the recursion:
function Get-LoopingPath {
    Param(
        $Node,
        # Limit path to x hops
        [int]$Limit = 5
    )

    Begin {
        # Initialize Array
        if($MatchList -eq $null) { $MatchList = @() }
    }

    Process {
        if($Limit -ne 0) {
            try   { 
                # Next potential node
                $pathsPossible = $script:testdata | ? { $_.Item2 -eq $Node.Item1 }
            }
            catch { 
                break
            }

            foreach($next in $pathsPossible) {
                $MatchList = @($Node, $next)
                Get-LoopingPath -Node $next -Limit ($Limit - 1)
            }
        }
    }

    End {
        return $MatchList
    }
}

And how I'm calling that function:
for($i=0; $i -lt 4; $i++) {
    $results = (Get-LoopingPath -Node $testdata[$i]).Row | Get-Unique
    if($results.count -gt 1) { [array]::Reverse($results) }
    Write-Host ("[{0}] {1}" -f $i,($results -join " > "))
}

And here's sample output:
[0] Row03 > Row01 > Row06 > Row03 > Row06 > Row03 > Row02 > Row03  
[1]   
[2] Row06 > Row03 > Row06 > Row03 > Row02 > Row03  
[3] Row04  
Unfortunately, I'm running into issues where the returned results from the function don't follow the logic of Item2 matches Item1, far exceeds the step limit, or returns a blank, non-null object.
I'm hoping to get this to a point where I can set a limit on the number of hops, and only return those at or below that limit which loop back to the starting row passed to the function. Once I can get the function working, the next step is comparing Item1 to Item3, then sorting the results from both searches by cost.
Recursive looping has always been hard for me to get right, so hoping for some pointers or suggestions.
Thanks.

Powershell isn't my forte but it looks like you can transform the table into a directed graph where nodes are rows in the table and a node has a directed edge to another only if the its Item1 column is equal to the other's Item2 column. From here cycle detection can be done using some graph traversal algorithm, like depth-first-search or breadth-first-search. This gfg article lists a few.

You need to pass the Row number into the function so you do skip the first matching entry.

Per @wLui155, you’re basically looking for cycles in a directed graph. You also haven’t explicitly said, but what happens if there’s more than one cycle in the data? Do you need to find the one optimised for some value (e.g. shortest cycle, the one with the largest weighted value by some measure, etc) or is it enough that you stop after you’ve found the first cycle?

I need to return all available paths that loop back to start, along with a weighted score which will be used to sort the results. I also need to remove the last entry on the loop since it is just a repeat of the starting point, but that can be done once I have the results.

Also, thanks for the gfg article. It looks promising. Now I just need to read up on it so I know what its saying.
